# Using other college/universities notes for practice?

Tags: copyright, exams

I like to get as much practice as I can before an exam so is it permissable to use other colleges or universities' practice exams or handouts for practice. I am not distributing them to anyone, selling them or profiting. Just want to get as much practice as possible. I was wondering if this is ok?

Comment: You want to study and it is OK. I am wondering why this may not be OK.

Comment: I'm worried I am violating copyright by using materials of another institution without being a student there. I am not distributing them or anything, just using them to study/learn but I just want to be 100% sure I am not doing anything wrong because I don't know much about the copyright and fair use laws

Comment: **Reading does not violate copyright.**

Answer (score 3):

If they've put it up freely available online, then they have made it available for people like yourself to read. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Studying universities practice exams, handouts, pamphlets, books, etc. is perfect only if you respect their privacy and rights.

Comment: yeah I'm not 100% sure what their privacy and rights entail. Can I use it for my own studying and delete them after? I use google to find the files, download them then study off them and delete them after is that violation of anything?

Comment: @Practice You should look at the copy rights of the content you are downloading. Some academic publications are only available for universities' own students, while some other are published publicly to be used by other students too. I can not generally tell you what you can do.